# Why is this Resizeable Element Increasing Size after changing its type

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Please look at this fiddle and why is this increasing size after reapplying the Resizable..
i want to add the Resizable file into this fiddle also.
  http://jsfiddle.net/RAPRa/1/

Answer (score 0):

try adding !important to your resizable class' width and height.

```
.resizable { 
   width: 150px !important; 
   height: 20px !important; 
   padding: 0em; 
}
```